# Spring Boot soap + hibernate configuration

Tags: spring, hibernate, soap

I have already a soap ws working with spring boot.

My doubt now its how to add in WebAppInitializer file the injection of Hibernate.

My file its like this now

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {  
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();  
        ctx.register(AppConfig.class);  
        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);    
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(ctx);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        Dynamic dynamic = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher",servlet);  
        dynamic.addMapping("/soapws/*");  
        dynamic.setLoadOnStartup(1);  
    }  
}
```

How to add the hibernate configuration/injection?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the spring boot starter jpa. Include the below dependency in your pom.xml (if using maven).

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And then, specify hibernate options in application.properties. For example,

```
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy =     org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

etc

Spring Boot tries to guess the location of your @Entity definitions, based on the @EnableAutoConfiguration it finds. To get more control, you can use the @EntityScan annotation
Refer to this for more details :

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html